# React Native states not updating value after changing value

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, render

I am new to `React-Native` and its `states`, here I am stuck with a problem (using dummy data but my problem is same) all I want to achieve is get the latest `JSONARRAY` fetched from the `state`, based on button clicks when I click on button one it should only return `[{"one":"oneKey"},{"key":"mutatedFruit"}]` and similar approach for other buttons as well any help is appreciated
I have attached my

[expo snack code here](https://snack.expo.io/@rajatsingh661/demo-states)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope the below code helps ,

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View,Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';
 const data = [
   {"joinedUsers":[{"one":"oneKey"}],"key":"mango"}
 ,{"joinedUsers":[{"two":"twoKey"}],"key":"apple"}
 ,{"joinedUsers":[{"three":"threeKey"}],"key":"banana"}
 ,{"joinedUsers":[{"four":"fourKey"}],"key":"kiwi"}];
// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      selectedPosition:0,
     valueArr : []
    }
  }


  componentDidMount(){
    let newVal = [];
    newVal.push(data[0].joinedUsers[0]) 
    newVal.push({"key":"mutatedFruit"})
    this.setState({valueArr:newVal})

  }


  setValues = (position) => {
      let newVal = [];
       newVal.push(data[position].joinedUsers[0]) 
    newVal.push({"key":"mutatedFruit"})
    this.setState({valueArr:newVal})
  }

  render() {
    const value = data[this.state.selectedPosition].joinedUsers
    value.push({"key":"mutatedFruit"})

    return ( 
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title='ONE'
        onPress={()=>this.setValues(0)}></Button>
        <Button title='TWO'
        onPress={()=>this.setValues(1)}></Button>
        <Button title='THREE'
        onPress={()=>this.setValues(2)}></Button>
        <Button title='FOUR'
        onPress={()=>this.setValues(3)}></Button>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.valueArr)}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
    flexDirection:'column'
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: It actually solved my problem thanks.
Just curious what was wrong with my code? Does pushing into array retaining the value or is it related to saving the current data into state first then update it?

Comment: Need help again please join the chat room where we were discussing yesterday

Comment: Okay. Around 2 or 3 I'll join.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Based on your comment, it sounds like your issue is you don't want the same value added multiple times. In that case, this should fix it:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state= {
    selectedPosition:0,
  }

  render() {
    const value = data[this.state.selectedPosition].joinedUsers
    value[0]["key"] = "mutatedFruit"

    return ( 
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title='ONE'
        onPress={()=>this.setState({selectedPosition:0})}></Button>
        <Button title='TWO'
        onPress={()=>this.setState({selectedPosition:1})}></Button>
        <Button title='THREE'
        onPress={()=>this.setState({selectedPosition:2})}></Button>
        <Button title='FOUR'
        onPress={()=>this.setState({selectedPosition:3})}></Button>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(value)}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you very much for your answer but I have already tried by using a function too it doesnt solve the problem and moreover I get values in the output too like I have presses  button 1 already and if I again press button 1 it return new value and old ones too

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what your question was? So your problem is that it adds new values every time?

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Edited again. I changed the line to value[0]["key"] = "mutatedFruit"

Comment: Do you think this code will break?, If I change state from any where in `render()` function and one last thing what is the meaning of `value[0]['key']=''Mutated Fruit"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204024/discussion-between-rajat-singh-and-phoenixb).